# Ao rodar 'ionic build ios' no macOS com node 7 recebo uma mensagem 'stdout maxBuffer exceeded'. Como resolver?

Tags: node.js, ionic, ios, osx

De repente eu comecei a ter esse problema quando tento buildar meu app com `ionic build ios` . Não entendo o que pode ter acontecido porque estava rodando normal em um dia, mas no dia seguinte apresentou esse erro:

```
...
...
Running command: HC-Ionic/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js HC-Ionic

Running command: HC-Ionic/hooks/after_prepare/020_remove_sass_from_platforms.js HC-Ionic


stdout maxBuffer exceeded
```

A única coisa que eu fiz que me recordo antes de dar problema foi mudar a versão do node algumas vezes usando 'n'. Mas eu já desinstalei todas as versões do node que eu tinha, deixei apenas a correta, mas continuo tendo o problema.

As versões no meu sistema são essas:

```
Cordova CLI: 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS
Node Version: v7.10.1
Xcode version: Xcode 12.4 Build version 12D4e
```

Essa configuração é necessária porque meu app só builda com essa versão 7 do node, por conta que algumas libs não rodam nas versões mais atuais.

Alguém passou por algo parecido?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução, aparentemente a quantidade de simuladores que eu tinha no xcode estava excedendo o json que precisava ser printado no build. Se a lista de simuladores exceder 200KB o node 7 não compila. Removi alguns simuladores desnecessários e funcionou